# How to restore multiple transaction logs using SMO for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo

I am working on a database application to restore a database with its transaction logs. I am using the SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Library.

The requirements of this application make it so that I must restore the database backup file and its transaction logs in separate processes. I can restore the backup file without a hitch however, when it comes to restoring the transaction logs I come across a problem:

```
        public void RestoreTransactionLogs(Server srv, DirectoryInfo filePath, DatabaseType dbType)
        {
            Restore res = new Restore()
            {
                Database = dbType.ToString(),
                Action = RestoreActionType.Log,
                ReplaceDatabase = false
            };

            FileInfo[] files = filePath.Parent.GetFiles("*.trn");

            foreach (FileInfo f in files)
            {
                res.Devices.AddDevice(f.FullName, DeviceType.File);
            }           

            try
            {
                res.SqlRestore(srv);
            }
            catch (SmoException ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal("An SMO Exception has occurred when restoring the database: " + dbType.ToString() + ": " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal("An exception has occurred when restoring the database:  " + dbType.ToString() + ": " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Using a test backup file and 20 transaction logs, I run into the following error:

> SmoException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The media loaded on
>   "D:\Test Folder\testDatabase\log_00001.trn" is formatted to support
>   1 media families, but 20 media families are expected according to the
>   backup device specification.

I have a feeling I am not adding the transaction logs to my device collection properly or I should be adding them in a different manner but I am unsure where to check. The documentation from MSDN for transaction logs is scarce and I haven't been able to find much online. Thanks!

Comment: Can you restore using SQL Server Management Studio?  The Net library methods usually only work with the same version of SQL Server they were generated while SSMS is often backwards compatible.

Comment: hmm, looks like I get the same error in Management Studio. These files were backed up in SQL Server 2008 and I am using SQL Server 2017 so it could be caused by an incompatibility?

Comment: See following : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183494/can-sql-server-2016-log-files-be-applied-on-sql-server-2012/183495

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you can't restore just a transaction log. You have to start with a full backup first and then apply the transaction log(s). This must happen while db is in no recovery state and thus no other change to the db occurs between the full backup restore and the transaction log restore. Also, keep in mind that you have to apply transaction logs in the order they were taken.

Here is what I got working based on the doco example here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/backing-up-and-restoring-databases-and-transaction-logs?view=sql-server-ver15

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
    Database targetDb = server.Databases["TargetDbName"];

    // Make sure your user has ALTER ANY CONNECTION rights for this
    // not needed if you can be sure db is not in use
    server.KillAllProcesses(targetDb.Name);
    targetDb.SetOffline();

    Restore restoreDB = new Restore();
    restoreDB.Database = targetDb.Name;
    restoreDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    restoreDB.ReplaceDatabase = true;

    // Restore the full backup first
    var fullBackupDevice = new BackupDeviceItem("fullBackupFile.bak", DeviceType.File);
    restoreDB.Devices.Add(fullBackupDevice);
    restoreDB.NoRecovery = true;
    restoreDB.SqlRestore(server);
    restoreDB.Devices.Remove(fullBackupDevice);

    // Get the first taken transaction log file
    var firstTransactionBackupDevice = new BackupDeviceItem("firstTrnFile.trn", DeviceType.File);
    restoreDB.Devices.Add(firstTransactionBackupDevice);
    restoreDB.SqlRestore(server);
    restoreDB.Devices.Remove(firstTransactionBackupDevice);

    // Get the second taken transaction log file
    var secondTransactionBackupDevice = new BackupDeviceItem("secondTrnFile.trn", DeviceType.File);
    restoreDB.Devices.Add(secondTransactionBackupDevice);
    // You have to set this flag to false before the last file you will restore
    // to return the db to the normal state
    restoreDB.NoRecovery = false;
    restoreDB.SqlRestore(server);
    restoreDB.Devices.Remove(secondTransactionBackupDevice);

    targetDb.SetOnline();
    server.Refresh();
}
```

I know your question is a bit older and you've probably found a solution already, but hopefully this helps to someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Hi man you can try the scripts below within your sql server. Do change the directory file path. Also do your research on "with recovery" and "no recovery" .. example beow

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DW] FROM DISK = 'G:\MSSQL\Data\FullBackups\db.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
Go
RESTORE DATABASE [DW] FROM DISK = 'G:\MSSQL\Data\DifferentialBackups\db.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
--repeat how many ever times if multiple based on time DB crashed.
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [DW] FROM DISK = 'G:\MSSQL\Data\TransactionLogs\db.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
--Final T-Log to exact point in time recovery.
RESTORE DATABASE [DW] FROM DISK = 'G:\MSSQL\Data\TransactionLogs\db.bak' WITH RECOVERY
```

Comment: This is using straight SQL to restore differential backups. My question is in regards to using the SMO Library with .NET...